# Where can I find a Nashorn browser?

Tags: java, web-browser

I'm looking for a browser that uses the [Nashorn engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) ([article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html)) instead of SpiderMonkey or V8, etc. Do any browsers use this engine yet?

Comment: There probably isn't one, since it's not intended to be run in a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sort of

In [gngr](https://github.com/UprootLabs/gngr) we are using [rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/) as the engine. Rhino is a close cousin of Nashorn. If you only need Nashorn, it might be conceivable to switch the engines with some effort.

The reason we are using Rhino is:

- We don't yet have the resources to port to Nashorn.
- We might want to support Java 7 in the future.
- Having the JS engine as a separate Jar helps sandboxing it. (If Nashorn is loaded by the system class loader, as I suspect it is, it won't be possible to sandbox it).
- Nashorn seems to add some bindings to the global scope with no way to turn it off. (This is from vague memory; I had brought this up on the Nashorn mailing list about an year back and was told that this behavior won't be changed).

Comment: You have lots of questions :) Thanks for looking into it. Would be happy to answer. On IRC we are at #gngr on freenode, and /r/gngr on Reddit. Reddit would be best for this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

## Not Likely

While there could conceivably be a web browser using Nashorn as its JavaScript/ECMAScript engine, that is not likely. Such usage is not the purpose of Nashorn.

Instead, Nashorn is [aimed at these two purposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)):

- Embedding JavaScript within a Java app.
  Sometimes a Java app wants to run some code or library written in JavaScript.
- Develop standalone JavaScript apps to run on the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Comment: But what if there is a java app which is also a browser :) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Web-K](https://github.com/Earnix/Web-K) is a basic web view which integrates Flying Saucer as a renderer, JSoup as parser and Nashorn as JS runtime with basic DOM-related features.